# Unity - can't find an object in List

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, find

I ran into some problem in Unity, How am I supposed to remove an item from a List by its ID or name? I think this should work, but evidentally it doesn't.

```
....
List<MyDataType> myList = new List<MyDataType>();
....
public static void removeItemFromList(int id)
{
    foreach (MyDataType item in myList)
    {
        if (item.TypeId == id)
        Debug.Log("List contains ID: " + item.TypeId);
    }
// PRINTS AN OBJECT WITH THE ID - works as expected

    var match = myList.Find(p => p.TypeId == id);
// SEEMS LIKE IT CAN'T FIND THE OBJECT WITH THE ID

    if (match == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("DOES NOT EXIST");
        return;
    }
// always returns DOES NOT EXIST, WHY?

    myList.Remove(match);


}
```

Comment: What if you change .Find to .FirstOrDefault(p => p.TypeId == id) ?

Comment: System.Collections.Generic.List<MyDataType> does not contain definition for .FirstOrDefault but I think I solved it tho.
Instead of if (match == null) I used if (match.TypeId == null) and it seems to be working. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

I don't have unity in front of me,
but you could try `myList.Select(item => item.TypeId == id).SingleOrDefault();`

or as Fabjan states:

`myList.SingleOrDefault(item => item.TypeId == id);`

Answer (score 0):

Jasper is correct, but make sure that you add the LINQ library to your project or you won't have access to FirstOrDefault on a list. That may be why you couldn't find the definition for it.

```
using System.Linq;
```